# Spark output JSON vs Parquet file size discrepancy

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

new Spark user here. i wasn't able to find any information about filesize comparison between JSON and parquet output of the same dataFrame via Spark.

testing with a very small data set for now, doing a df.toJSON().collect() and then writing to disk creates a 15kb file. but doing a df.write.parquet creates 105 files at around 1.1kb each. why is the total file size so much larger with parquet in this case than with JSON?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

what you're doing with df.toJSON.collect is you get a single JSON from all your data (15kb in your case) and you save that to disk - this is not something scalable for situations you'd want to use Spark in any way.

For saving parquet you are using spark built-in function and it seems that for some reason you have 105 partitions (probably the result of the manipulation you did) so you get 105 files. Each of these files has the overhead of the file structure and probably stores 0,1 or 2 records. if you want to save a single file you should coalesce(1) before you save (again this just for the toy example you have) so you'd get 1 file. Note that it still might be larger due to the file format overhead (i.e. the overhead might still be larger than the compression benefit)

Answer (score 0):

Conan, it is very hard to answer your question precisely without knowing the nature of the data (you don't even tell amount of row in your DataFrame). But let me speculate.

First. Text files containing JSON usually take more space on disk then parquet. At least when one store millions-billions rows. The reason for that is parquet is highly optimized column based storage format which uses a binary encoding to store your data

Second. I would guess that you have a very small dataframe with 105 partitions (and probably 105 rows). When you store something that small the disk footprint should not bother you but if it does you need to be aware that each parquet file has a relatively sizeable header describing the data you store.